# MacOS ZIP file contains unwanted folder

Tags: windows, macos, zip, compression, macos-ventura

I've recently started university as a computer science student and I have to zip my code files and upload them to the universities server, but I have a Mac and when I tried to upload the zip file it said there were too many items in the zip file. Eventually I discovered that files compressed on Mac contains a folder named "_MACOSX" folder. Is there a way to compress files on Mac without having an additional folder or can I delete that folder somehow from that zip file?

I pretty sure there is a way to remove that folder with the terminal, but not so sure how can I do it. If you have an easier solution please let me know.

Comment: How are you zipping the files? Are you doing that in macOS? With what command?

Comment: With PeaZip you should be able to compress without this folder and also remove the folder from .zip files:
https://peazip.github.io/peazip-macos.html